Message selector in Azure service bus is not working - AMQP
How are you ? Hope you are doing good .
I have faced some technical challenges in Azure service bus and Qpid client .
I am sending JMS message from Jakarta jms and I am using qpid jms client as Listener .
Azure service bus is my Message Broker .
Even though after sending message with proper selector , the listener with proper message selector receiving all the messages from the queue . it is not filtering as per JMSCorrelationID and with other properties .
 String selector = "JMSCorrelationID = '" + correlationId + "'";
MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(queue, selector); 


The issue you're running into is due to the fact that Service Bus Standard Tier does not support MessageSelector objects. You can refer to Microsoft's documentation here. (The compatibility issue is noted at the very end of the document).
Meanwhile, if you'd like to use this functionality, you're going to have to:

Upgrade to Azure Service Bus Premium Tier.
Make sure that you're using the Java Message Service v2 API.

Once you've met those requirements, you should be able to correctly use your MessageSelector.
According to Microsoft Documentation here, the following is, in fact supported in the Premium Tier + v2 API scenario:
JMSContext.createConsumer( Destination destination, String messageSelector);


Thanks , I am using latest version V2 of JMS and QPID Version -  jakarta.jms-api-3.1.0 .
But not with  Azure Service Bus Premium Tier. I will try Thanks
